# Issues connecting to Lawicel with Python

Tags: python, can-bus

We are trying to send and receive CAN messages using the Lawicel hardware.
So far i have tried simple serial approach and it is not working.

On trying to import from 
can.interfaces.serial.serialcom import SerialInterface

Error is received as "Interface not found.

Comment: Try to ping this [pull request](https://github.com/hardbyte/python-can/pull/290). Once reworked and merged it would let you use SLCAN protocol directly via serial port interface.

Comment: Sorry, but i am no sure on how do i do that, could you suggest something